# Setting SonarJava 4.12 analysis with Travis.CI (bytecode issues)

Tags: java, android, sonarqube, travis-ci

According to [this](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/SonarJava), Sonarqube now requires bytecode in order to properly check Java code.
I had a working Travis CI+SonarQube workflow which is now broken due to the new demand.

I am having trouble setting up the new workflow.

This is the error I get:

> ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: No files nor directories matching '/home/travis/build/My_user_name/My_project_name/app/build/intermediates/classes/'
>       at org.sonar.java.AbstractJavaClasspath.getFilesFromProperty(AbstractJavaClasspath.java:93)
>       at org.sonar.java.JavaClasspath.init(JavaClasspath.java:49)
>       at org.sonar.java.AbstractJavaClasspath.getElements(AbstractJavaClasspath.java:281)
>       at org.sonar.java.SonarComponents.getJavaClasspath(SonarComponents.java:141)
>       at org.sonar.java.JavaSquid.(JavaSquid.java:83)
>       at org.sonar.plugins.java.JavaSquidSensor.execute(JavaSquidSensor.java:83)
>       at org.sonar.scanner.sensor.SensorWrapper.analyse(SensorWrapper.java:53)
>       at org.sonar.scanner.phases.SensorsExecutor.executeSensor(SensorsExecutor.java:88)
>       at org.sonar.scanner.phases.SensorsExecutor.execute(SensorsExecutor.java:82)
>       at org.sonar.scanner.phases.SensorsExecutor.execute(SensorsExecutor.java:68)
>       at org.sonar.scanner.phases.AbstractPhaseExecutor.execute(AbstractPhaseExecutor.java:78)
>       at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ModuleScanContainer.doAfterStart(ModuleScanContainer.java:179)
>       at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:144)
>       at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:129)
>       at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scan(ProjectScanContainer.java:261)
>       at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:256)
>       at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doAfterStart(ProjectScanContainer.java:245)
>       at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:144)
>       at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:129)
>       at org.sonar.scanner.task.ScanTask.execute(ScanTask.java:47)
>       at org.sonar.scanner.task.TaskContainer.doAfterStart(TaskContainer.java:84)
>       at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:144)
>       at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:129)
>       at org.sonar.scanner.bootstrap.GlobalContainer.executeTask(GlobalContainer.java:119)
>       at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.executeTask(Batch.java:116)
>       at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.batch.BatchIsolatedLauncher.execute(BatchIsolatedLauncher.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
>       at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherProxy.invoke(IsolatedLauncherProxy.java:60)
>       at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.execute(Unknown Source)
>       at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.doExecute(EmbeddedScanner.java:233)
>       at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.runAnalysis(EmbeddedScanner.java:151)
>       at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.runAnalysis(Main.java:110)
>       at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.execute(Main.java:74)
>       at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.main(Main.java:61)

I do not know where Travis stores my Android ByteCode files or how to properly tell SonarQube their location.

**Edit:**
sonar-project.properties:

```
# must be unique in a given SonarQube instance
sonar.projectKey=key:dev
# sonar.branch=${branch}
# this is the name and version displayed in the SonarQube UI. Was mandatory prior to SonarQube 6.1.
sonar.projectName=name
sonar.projectVersion=1.40

# Path is relative to the sonar-project.properties file. Replace "\" by "/" on Windows.
# Since SonarQube 4.2, this property is optional if sonar.modules is set. 
# If not set, SonarQube starts looking for source code from the directory containing 
# the sonar-project.properties file.
sonar.sources=app/src

sonar.java.binaries=app/build/intermediates/classes/

# Encoding of the source code. Default is default system encoding
#sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8

sonar.exclusions=R.java, /build
sonar.language=java

sonar.junit.reportsPath=build/outputs/androidTest-results/connected/
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your build/analysis configuration.

Comment: @G.Ann-SonarSourceTeam done

Comment: For an Android project, don't you use Gradle to do the build?

Comment: I do. What is missing?

Answer (score 0):

Your use of a `sonar-project.properties` file indicates that you're trying to analyze with SonarQube Scanner. While that is the generic solution, it's not best for all cases. Since you're already using Gradle to build your Android project, I'd use the [SonarQube Scanner for Gradle](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Gradle), which will automatically understand where both your byte code and your source files are.

Comment: Thank you. I've tried it, but now it gives this error: 
ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
ERROR: You must define the following mandatory properties for 'Unknown': sonar.projectKey, sonar.sources
This is the build.gradle file: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aayaffe/SailingRaceCourseManager/master/app/build.gradle

Comment: For Gradle 2.1+, the plugin should be `id "org.sonarqube" version "2.5"`